# How to exclude 1 menu item in wp_nav_menu( array(?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

It contains 
    Home,
    Company,
    Help & Support,
    Products,
    Pricing, and
    Sign In.

I use this in the navbar in the header and i will be using it on the footer. In footer it will only display all of the menu items excluding Sign in. What should i do? Im new to wordpress.

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu'              => 'primarynav',
    'depth'             => 2,
    'container'         => 'div',
    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav')
);
?>
```

Comment: why not hide it using css? if you can't create a separate menu for footer

Comment: i dont know how to determine the menu item 'sign in' since the menu is not static :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** login to your cpanel root directory of WordPress then open **wp-content -> themes -> your theme -> functions.php**

**Step 2:** In **functions.php** file create secondary navigation something like this

```
register_nav_menus( array(  
  'secondary' => __('Secondary Navigation', 'twentyten')  
) );
```

put your theme name instead of twentyten

**Step :3** now open **wp-content -> themes -> your theme -> footer.php**
where you would like to call footer menu use this code

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu( array(
     'menu'              => 'Secondary Navigation',
     'depth'             => 2,
     'container'         => 'div',
     'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
     'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
     'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav')
);
?>
```

**Step:4** log in to your **admin end** and **appearance -> menus -> create new menu -> add the menus** exclude sign in and tick the box Secondary Navigation

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by Minal Chauhan is correct. That is the one way by which you can do the things that you want.

Another way is keeping the same menu in admin, you just need to add class to "sign in" menu.

Here is the screenshot to describe how you can give class to particular menu item

[image]

If you are not able to view CSS Classes field, you have to enable it from screen option which is located in top right corner.
Here is the screenshot how to enable Class option for menu items:

[image]

Now, after giving class you need to write following jQuery code:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('footer .test').closest('li').remove(); // here .test is the class which I gave to my menu item. And Footer is parent div element from where I want to apply this jQuery code. // these selectors you may need to change as per your HTML code.
});

Please let me know if you need any further help.

Thanks!